# How to retrieve access-token from GCP Golang SDK?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, sdk

We are implementing an application for GCP which needs the oauth2 bearer token to authenticate docker against GCR. The application is written in Go and it uses the GCP SDK for Golang.

I'd like to get what `gcloud auth print-access-token` give from the SDK, but I don't find how to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`oauth2/google`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2/google).

You may (!?) be able to use workload identity federation (using this library too and thereby avoid using a Google Service Account key) but, using a Service Account (with `roles/storage.objectAdmin` see [GCR: Granting IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#grant)) and Application Default Credentials (`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/your/key.json`) look at [`DefaultTokenSource`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2/google#DefaultTokenSource).

The [Token](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2@v0.0.0-20211104180415-d3ed0bb246c8#Token) returned by `Token()` from [`TokenSource`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2@v0.0.0-20211104180415-d3ed0bb246c8#TokenSource) gives you an `access_token` (and `refresh_token` and expiry).

###### Update

You can use the Service Account key file [directly](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json-key) to authenticate a Docker client to GCR. This would simplify your code (and avoid refreshing). The document reiterates the caution in using Service Account keys.

Comment: I am using "workload identity" in GKE. I want to use Kubernetes ServiceAccount for authenticating workload. How can I make `DefaultTokenSource` to use it?